# File Size Reduction in Pandas and HDF5

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I am running a model that outputs data into multiple Pandas frames, and then saves those frames to an HDF5 file. The model is run several hundred times, each time adding new columns (multi-indexed) into the existing HDF5 file's frames. This is done with Pandas `merge`. Since the frames are different lengths for each run, there ends up being a large number of `NaN` values in the frames.

After enough model runs are completed, data are dropped from the frames if the rows or columns are associated with a model run that had an error. In that process, the new data frames are put into a new HDF5 file. the following pseudo-python shows this process:

```
with pandas.HDFStore(filename) as store:
    # figure out which indices should be removed
    indices_to_drop = get_bad_indices(store)

    new_store = pandas.HDFStore(reduced_filename) 
    for key in store.keys():
        df = store[key]
        for idx in indices_to_drop:
             df = df.drop(idx, <level and axis info>)
        new_store[key] = df
    new_store.close()
```

The new hdf5 file ends up being about 10% of the size of the original. The only difference in the files is that all the `NaN` values are no longer equal (but are all numpy float64 values).

My question is, how can this filesize reduction (presumably through managing `NaN` values) be achieved on an existing hdf5 file? There are times where I don't need to do the above procedure, but I am doing it anyway to get the reduction. Is there an existing Pandas or PyTables command that can do this? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#delete-from-a-table)

The warning says it all:

> Warning Please note that HDF5 DOES NOT RECLAIM SPACE in the h5 files
>   automatically. Thus, repeatedly deleting (or removing nodes) and
>   adding again WILL TEND TO INCREASE THE FILE SIZE. To clean the file,
>   use ptrepack

Comment: yes, this worked for me, from 98GB to 17GB, i had not known this and my hdf file size kept on growing,